# firebase SDK installation issue

Tags: firebase, sprite-kit, admob

I am trying to install admob in my app which I built using spritekit.My os Sierra version is 10.12.3.This is my first time attempting so long story short, I inserted `GoogleService-Info.plist` into my project and managed to locate my project and it looks like so

```
 "myNames"-MacBook-Pro:~ "firstandlastname"$ cd /Users/"firstlast"/Desktop/"myProject'sName"/
 "myNames"-MacBook-Pro:"myProject'sName" "firstandlastname"$
```

my issue here is that whenever I am trying to insert `pod init` it gives me this error `-bash: pod: command not found`

Any ideas as to why? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after much research, I worked out my rookie mistake. I will leave this here just in case someone runs into the same issue as I did. 
All I had to do was install cocoapods! There are plenty of tutorials that show you how. Again, rookie mistake of me.